# What is a trust region reflective algorithm?

Tags: optimization, least-squares

What is a trust region reflective algorithm? 
I know (from the matlab help) that it is used for solving constrained optimization problems.

How is it different than the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm and from the more general class of trust-region algorithms?

Also, why is it called "reflective"?

Comment: The author here has provided a mathematical explanation of the difference between the two algorithms. http://www.applied-mathematics.net/LMvsTR/LMvsTR.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I know this is many years too late, but for future readers, I found a good top-level description in the reference of SciPy's implementation of the algorithm: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html

From what I can gather, it modifies your typical trust-region method to avoid stepping into the boundaries of the problem. The "reflective" part comes from the fact that the algorithm "considers search directions reflected from the bounds", which apparently helps with convergence.